# Как изменить input type file?

Tags: html, css, input

Подскажите как убирается стандартное отображение type=file = Выберите файл/файл не выбран, а оставить мои стили  = Загрузить файл.

```css
.feedback__text {
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #282828;
}


.feedback__file {
  
}

.feedback__file:before {
            content: "Загрузить файл";
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 132px;
            height: 32px;
            margin: 11px 0 0;
            padding: 8px 20px 7px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #f5f6f7;
            font-family: OpenSans;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #282828;
}
```

```html
<p class="feedback__text">Документы</p>
<label for="file" class="feedback__label"></label>
<input type="file"  id="file" class="feedback__file">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.feedback__text {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #282828;
}

.feedback__label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 132px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 11px 0 0;
  padding: 8px 20px 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f6f7;
  color: #282828;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.feedback__file {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="feedback__text">Документы</p>
<label class="feedback__label">
  Загрузить файл
  <input type="file" id="file_in" class="feedback__file">
</label>

<!-- Или так... -->

<p class="feedback__text">Документы</p>
<label for="file_out" class="feedback__label">Загрузить файл</label>
<input type="file" id="file_out" class="feedback__file">
```

Comment: А я типо все время к инпуту все применял а нужно было к lable.
Визуально то что нужно, в плане разметки конечно фиг знает p label input насколько правильно.

Comment: @faradei: это стандартное решение и в плане разметки всё правильно.